# how to reference cells from another sheet in indirect function

Tags: excel, reference

I am using this formula in my excel sheet, =COUNTA(INDIRECT("B2:B" & ROW()-1))

but I want to reference column B from Another Sheet called List.
Can you please help.

I am basically trying to get the number of rows in a sheet called List, where rows are continuously added and range is not fixed.

Comment: =COUNTA(INDIRECT("List!B2:B" & ROW()-1))

Comment: tried this, it is not working

Comment: What is your actual goal? What about `=COUNTA(INDIRECT("List!B:B"))`?

Comment: The correct formula has been provided.  If you "tried this, it is not working", then you asked an irrelevant  question.  "Rows are continuously added and range is not fixed", this is called a dynamic range, search Google for working examples.